# Select last record of each person

Tags: mysql, subquery, left-join

I have the following tables

**tbl_investors**

```
   id  |   first_name  |  last_name  |
---------------------------------------
   1   |      Jon      |    Cold     |
   2   |      Rob      |    Ark      |
   3   |     Rickon    |    Bolt     |
```

**tbl_investors_ledger**

```
  id   |   investor_id  |  amount  |
------------------------------------
  1    |        1       |   500    |
  2    |        2       |   200    |
  3    |        2       |   250    |
  4    |        2       |   300    |
  5    |        3       |   10     |
  6    |        1       |   550    |
  7    |        3       |   20     |
```

I just want to return all investors with their latest amount. Ex, Jon Cold with 550, Rob Ark 300 and Rickon Bolt 20, alphabetically with their last name.

I have an existing query but it will not return the latest amount of the investor. Can someone help me what i'm doing wrong?

```
   SELECT t1.*, t2.*
   FROM ".tbl_investors." t1
   LEFT JOIN ".tbl_investors_ledger." t2
        ON t1.id = t2.investor_id
   LEFT JOIN (SELECT t.investor_id, max(t.id) as tid 
        FROM ".tbl_investors_ledger." t ) tt
        ON tt.investor_id = t2.investor_id AND tt.tid = t2.id
   GROUP BY t2.investor_id 
   ORDER BY t1.last_name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this;)

```
 SELECT t1.*, t2.*
 FROM tbl_investors t1
 LEFT JOIN tbl_investors_ledger t2
 ON t1.id = t2.investor_id
 INNER JOIN (
     SELECT t.investor_id, max(t.id) as tid 
     FROM tbl_investors_ledger t GROUP BY t.investor_id) tt
 ON tt.investor_id = t2.investor_id AND tt.tid = t2.id
 ORDER BY t1.last_name
```

[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/439a8/1)

And check related OP [Retrieving the last record in each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group?rq=1) and this blog [How to select the first/least/max row per group in SQL](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/), you can find more solutions for your question.

Comment: thanks for your prompt reply @10086, it worked! I have this problem almost a day already and i tried my best not to ask. You just solve it like seconds!!! awesome, thank again!

Comment: @zen You're welcome. And do more google will be helpful.

Comment: I tried, i'm quite new to this, anyhow u are awesome!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) and [SUBSTRING_INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) together

```
SELECT I.*
    , SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(L.amount ORDER BY L.id DESC), ',', 1) AS LastAmount
    FROM tbl_investors AS I
    LEFT JOIN tbl_investors_ledgers AS L
        ON L.investor_id = I.id
    GROUP BY I.id
    ORDER BY I.last_name
```

Here a demo from [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/32620/5), many thanks to @zakhefron :)

Comment: having an error: Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$amount @KaeL

Comment: Its working @KaeL . Different thinking. Demo for above query [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/32620/5)

Comment: Haha thanks @zakhefron! I don't have access to sqlfiddle at the moment that's why I can't create one. I'm updating my answer with your link.